# I want to create custom token for 24 hours, but it validates on firebase only if it is created for 1 hour. Is there any specific reason to this?

Tags: firebase, jwt, token

i am using this array to generate jwt token

```
$payload = array(
          "iss" => $service_account_email,
          "sub" => $service_account_email,
          "aud" => "https://identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/google.identity.identitytoolkit.v1.IdentityToolkit",
          "iat" => $now_seconds,
          "exp" => $now_seconds+(2*60*60),  // Maximum expiration time is 24 hours
          "uid" => $uid,
          "claims" => $additional_claims
        );
```

if in exp time i add (60*60), it validate token succesfully on firebase but if its more that 1 hour, its giving error.

Comment: For those of us who don't know so much about Firebase, you might want to add information about how your JWTs are being validated/checked after they get created.  Obviously, if you assign a certain expiry to the claims, we would assume it would be written as you requested.

Comment: But if i assign expiry time for more than 1 hour, its not getting validate on firebase.